# DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

When using the [Bootstrap integration](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) for DataTables, I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined (dataTables.bootstrap.js:20)
```

This causes the pagination controls to not have styles on them.

I can see that in the factory initialization, the following code needs to run:

```
factory( jQuery, jQuery.fn.dataTable );
```

However, `jQuery.fn.dataTable` is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The problem is that `dataTable` is not defined at the point you are calling this method.

Ensure that you are loading the `.js` files in the correct order:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found that I have loaded my files in correct order, but still getting the error and dataTables not working properly. Please help.

Comment: jQuery is the very first thing I load in my application and I still get this.

Comment: You probably aren't loading the buttons base js and the buttons bs js files

Comment: Still not working ... 
It's like this but It's suddenly stopped from Jun 2017 and not working now :-(

Comment: I tried this too but it's still not working. Still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, I'm using laravel 5.4 with webpack, here package.json before:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    ...
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "datatables.net": "^2.1.1",
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

I had to move `jquery` and `datatables.net` npm packages under one of these `"dependencies": {}` or `"devDependencies": {}` in `package.json` and the error disappeared, after:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "datatables.net": "^2.1.1",
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"defer</script>`

Add Defer to the end of your Script tag, it worked for me (;

Everything needs to be loaded in the correct order (:

Answer (score 0):

```
var datatable_jquery_script = document.createElement("script");
datatable_jquery_script.src = "vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(datatable_jquery_script);
setTimeout(function(){
    var datatable_bootstrap_script = document.createElement("script");
    datatable_bootstrap_script.src = "vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(datatable_bootstrap_script);
},100);
```

I used setTimeOut to make sure datatables.min.js loads first. I inspected the waterfall loading of each, bootstrap4.min.js always loads first.