# how to add a field in jquery data table?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to use JQuery data table in my Laravel project.

I have some fields in my MySQL db and show them in my UI.

For example i have name and family and date and **time**.

i want to show addition of time in my jquery datatable.that means if  i have  2 record in time one is 4 and another is 2 at the end of table show me 6.

```
<table id="list-report" class="table table-bordered responsive">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <th>explain</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th> date</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     @foreach($datas as $key=>$value)
        <tr>
            <td>{!!++$key!!}</td>
            <th>{{ str_limit($value->explain, $limit = 100, $end = '...') }}</th>
            <td>{{$value->time}}</td>
            <td class="date">{{$value->date}}
            </td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach                   
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

thanks a  lot.

Comment: read it again please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306423/how-to-display-total-of-a-column-in-the-last-row-of-a-datatable-generated-using

Comment: You are using client side or server side datatable?

Comment: i use server side database.

Comment: Post your jquery and html code to?

Comment: i use jquery datatable and laravel ok i post the code

Comment: jquery code is jquery datatable plugin.

Comment: post your expected out put

Comment: i want add another td to this table and in that td show Sum Of time.