# Getting Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using require and datatable. I have written the following code for datatable to work:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        bootstrap : 'lib/bootstrap',
        jquery : 'lib/jquery-1-9-0-min',
        datatable:'lib/jquery.dataTables',
        datatablebootstrapDT:'lib/DT_bootstrap',
    },
    shim : {
        bootstrap : {
            deps : [ 'jquery' ],
            exports : 'Bootstrap'
        },
        datatable:{
            deps : [ 'jquery' ],
            exports : 'DataTable',
        },
        datatablebootstrapDT:{
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'datatablebootstrap' ],
            exports : 'DatatablebootstrapDT'
        },
    }
});
```

I am getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined  in dataTables.bootstrap.js:2

below is the code at line 2

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
```

I googled a lot for this but no luck.

Comment: You appear to have a mismatched `}` in your JS.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165263/datatables-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-defaults-of-undefined

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is because i not copied correctly

Comment: @RohitArora Duplicate but situation are different and its included in correct order here