# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined @ dataTables.bootstrap.min.self

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Using the Bootstrap integration for DataTables, I saw the following error in the console

> :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefinedf @
>   dataTables.bootstrap.min.self.js? (anonymous function) @
>   dataTables.bootstrap.min.self.js?

Pagination controls to not have styles on them.

Comment: Similar problem [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165263/datatables-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-defaults-of-undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165263/datatables-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-defaults-of-undefined)